# Como consultar registro que não contenha determinado código?

Tags: query, oracle

Preciso fazer uma consulta onde sejam listados os chamados que não foram validados.
Funciona assim:

Um chamado é uma solicitação de suporte, na qual ocorrem diversas ações, e todas são registradas em uma tabela auxiliar.

Preciso filtrar todos os chamados que **não** tiveram a ação de código 140 registrado, por exemplo.

Minha consulta ficou assim:

```
select chamados from tb_chamados 
inner join tb_acoes on tb_acoes.cod_chamado = tb_chamados.cod_chamado
where tb_acoes.acao <> 140
```

O problema é que o resultado dessa consulta apenas ignora os registros onde a ação é igual a 140 e traz os demais.

Mas eu quero que a consulta me traga os chamados onde dentro dos registros de ações dele não conste nenhum que tenha o código 140.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é primeiro você fazer uma *subquery* com os chamados que tem a ação 140, e depois você faz um `select` nos chamados que **não** estão nesta *subquery*:

```
select * from tb_chamados
where cod_chamado not in -- chamados que não estão na lista abaixo (não tem ação 140)
(
  -- chamados que tem alguma ação 140
  select cod_chamado from
  (
    select cod_chamado, count(*) from tb_acoes
    where acao = 140
    group by cod_chamado
    having count(*) > 0
  )
)
```

---

No Oracle também é possível usar a [cláusula `WITH`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause). Com isso você define a *subquery* antes, e em seguida usa esta *subquery* para fazer a consulta.

A ideia é a mesma: a *subquery* verifica quais chamados tem a ação 140, depois o `select` pega todos os chamados que não estão nesta *subquery* (ou seja, que não tem a ação 140):

```
with chamados_140 as
(    
  -- chamados que tem alguma ação 140
    select cod_chamado, count(*) from tb_acoes
    where acao = 140
    group by cod_chamado
    having count(*) > 0
)
-- escolher os chamados que não estão em chamados_140 (não tem a ação 140)
select * from tb_chamados
where cod_chamado not in
  (select cod_chamado from chamados_140);
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/040f0/4).

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Acho que o código abaixo resolve seu problema pois ele pega todos os chamados que não exista uma ação 140 associada na tabela tb_acoes.

```
select chamados 
  from tb_chamados ch
 where not exists (select 1
                 from tb_acoes ac
                where ch.cod_chamado = ac.cod_chamado
                  and ac.acao = 140);
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o sinal **!=** para NÃO é Igual ou NOT IN (Valores), para NÃO contém estes valores.

```
select chamados from tb_chamados 
inner join tb_acoes on tb_acoes.cod_chamado = tb_chamados.cod_chamado
where tb_acoes.acao != 140
```

Ou

```
select chamados from tb_chamados 
inner join tb_acoes on tb_acoes.cod_chamado = tb_chamados.cod_chamado
where tb_acoes.acao NOT IN(140)
```